# Is a node in a tree considered its own ancestor?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree, clrs

I'm wondering what the consensus is on the definition of "ancestor" in a computer science context.

I only ask because in [Introduction to Algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms), Second Edition, p. 259 there is a description of the algorithm `Tree-Successor(x)` that seems odd. In finding the successor of node *x*,

> [...] if the right subtree of node *x* is empty and *x* has a successor *y*, then *y* is the lowest ancestor of *x* whose left child is also an ancestor of *x*.

In a binary search tree with a root having key `2` and children `1` and `3`, the successor of `1` is its parent `2`. In this case, *x* is the left child of *x*'s successor, *y*. According to the book's definition, then, *x* must be its own ancestor, unless I'm missing something.

I haven't found anything in the [errata](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~thc/clrs-bugs/bugs.php) about this.

Comment: So the song goes, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W7x1ETPkZsk

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's merely a matter of definition, but in this case, **yes**. CLRS define an ancestor of x as any node on the unique path from the root to x, which by definition includes x.

The sentence fragment you quoted begins by mentioning exercise 12.2-6 on the next page, which specifies this:

> (Recall that every node is its own ancestor.)

:-)

Comment: This must be the most precise answer on the Web :D

Answer (score 7):

> Is a node in a tree considered its own ancestor?

Not normally, AFAIK.  For example, in the Wikipedia page on [binary trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Definitions_for_rooted_trees), *ancestor* is defined thus:

> If a path exists from node p to node q, where node p is closer to the root node than q, then p is an ancestor of q and q is a descendant  of p.

But apparently that text book's definition of *ancestor* is such that a node is its own ancestor.  This definition is not exactly intuitive, but a textbook is free to introduce its own definitions for the terminology that it uses.  Maybe this definition simplifies some of the related descriptions / theorems / etc.

Answer (score -2):

No, a node is not ancestor of itself. According to me it should be: if the right subtree of node x is empty and x has a successor y, then y is the lowest ancestor of x whose left child is `either x or an ancestor of x.` but the code given in the book supposedly handling such type of cases.